# Is there any way to get the date modified of a file using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the date modified of a file located on another server, and not seeing any way to do so.  Is this possible to do in Node.js?

Comment: Did you try searching online before posting this questions?
`const lastModified = fs.statSync(filepath).mtime`

Answer (score 1):

[`fs.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback) or [`fs.statSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path_options) of [`fs.promises.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_stat_path_options) will all get you the date modified of any file you have file system access to.  The `.mtimeMs` or `.mtime` property of the Stats object those return will give you the last modification time.

If you don't have file system access to the file, then you will need a server process on that other system that you can make a request to (such as an http request) and have that server process fetch the date for you and return it to you.

Comment: @ro4jj - Does this answer your question?